# data transfer issue scientific notation

Tags: java, database, oracle, amazon-s3

I have a glue job that extracts data from an oracle database and store the data in s3. Now some of the columns which are in date format in the table present in oracle are converted to some exponential value. For example, date '2004-10-28 00:00:00' being converted to 4.5255526363240158946394112e+25

Comment: OK. What is your question then?

Comment: Can you debug code that you cannot see?  We know nothing about the source table, the target table, or the process used to move the data.

Comment: can you update your question with the script ? I believe this might due to the data type not correct for date columns in applymapping transformation